# Unable to publish custom story with mention tagging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, tagging, facebook-stream-story

My app was doing well yesterday and posting custom stories with mention tagging but from today its not working and telling me : -

```
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Unknown path components: /mynamespace:customaction
```

```php
Error code : 2500

{
  "error": {
             "message": "Unknown path components: /namespace:customaction", 
             "type": "OAuthException", 
             "code": 2500
           }
}
```

```php
$response = $facebook->api(
  'me/mynamespace:customaction',
  'POST',
  array(
    'treat' => "http://www.mywebsite.com/12321425125"
  )
);
```

I have not changed any configurations or anything and it has stopped working all of a sudden. Please help me identify the issue - maybe there is an issue at Facebook end.

Comment: First of all, check in your app dashboard if the custom action is still defined there.

Comment: our custom actions also stopped working overnight, no idea why

Comment: There is an open issue for this on the developers.facebook site
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/619299244769134